# How to draw circular bars?

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

I am devleoping a game with cocos2d-iphone.

I want to great a circular health bar. Think of Kingdom Hearts or something.

I am able to draw circles with `ccDrawLine`, but they are *full* circles. Basically, I need to be able to draw up to a certain circumference value to represent the health properly. However, I am not really sure about this. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I had a quick look at the code for ccDrawCircle.  If I was approaching this, I'd probably start by modifying the way the `for` loop works (maybe by playing with `coef` or `segs`) so that it stops early.

```
void ccDrawCircle( CGPoint center, float r, float a, NSUInteger segs, BOOL drawLineToCenter)
{
    int additionalSegment = 1;
    if (drawLineToCenter)
        additionalSegment++;

    const float coef = 2.0f * (float)M_PI/segs;

    GLfloat *vertices = calloc( sizeof(GLfloat)*2*(segs+2), 1);
    if( ! vertices )
        return;

    for(NSUInteger i=0;i<=segs;i++)
    {
        float rads = i*coef;
        GLfloat j = r * cosf(rads + a) + center.x;
        GLfloat k = r * sinf(rads + a) + center.y;

        vertices[i*2] = j * CC_CONTENT_SCALE_FACTOR();
        vertices[i*2+1] =k * CC_CONTENT_SCALE_FACTOR();
    }
    vertices[(segs+1)*2] = center.x * CC_CONTENT_SCALE_FACTOR();
    vertices[(segs+1)*2+1] = center.y * CC_CONTENT_SCALE_FACTOR();

    // Default GL states: GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_VERTEX_ARRAY, GL_COLOR_ARRAY, GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY
    // Needed states: GL_VERTEX_ARRAY, 
    // Unneeded states: GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY, GL_COLOR_ARRAY   
    glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    glDisableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);
    glDisableClientState(GL_COLOR_ARRAY);

    glVertexPointer(2, GL_FLOAT, 0, vertices);  
    glDrawArrays(GL_LINE_STRIP, 0, (GLsizei) segs+additionalSegment);

    // restore default state
    glEnableClientState(GL_COLOR_ARRAY);
    glEnableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);
    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);    

    free( vertices );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

CGContextAddArc() will do the trick. An example explains everything.

```
             CGContextAddArc(CGFloat centerX, CGFloat centerY, CGFloat radius, CGFloat startAngle, CGFloat endAngle, int clockwise);
```

I'm not quite sure about the order of the parameters, you'd better google it or let XCode do the work for you.